# Creating a Macro VBA Pop-out in powerpoint that, when page numbers are entered, will paste the selected to all the slides besides the ones selected

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was trying to create a paste to all macro that pastes the selected to all slides. However, I realized that I do not want it to be pasted to pages like the cover or the closing page, so I figured a good way to do it would be to have a pop-up appear when you run the macro and you can then select the pages you do not want it pasted to. It will then paste the selected to all of the slides except the ones entered.

I have the generic paste to all code, but am struggling to figure out how to implement the pop-out box. Any help would be appreciated!

Generic Paste to All Code:

```
Sub PasteToAll()
    
    Dim oshpR  As ShapeRange
    Dim T1     As Single
    Dim L1     As Single
    
    ActiveWindow.View.Paste
    
    Set oshpR = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    
    T1 = oshpR(1).Top
    
    L1 = oshpR(1).Left
    
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set MyRange = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.Paste
        MyRange(1).Left = L1
        MyRange(1).Top = T1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than expecting the users to remember the correct slide numbers to choose, why not let them select the slides they want to affect (in normal view/thumbnail pane or in slide sorter view). Then: Dim oSl as Slide | For each oSl in ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange | {do whatever} | Next   (replace each | with a CR/LF)

Comment: I am pretty new to VBA  -  would you know how I would go about doing that?  Thanks!

Comment: See the snippet of code in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Your code may create TWO shapes on the active slide (its index is ActiveWindow.View.slide.SlideIndex). `ActiveWindow.View.Paste` creates the 1st shape. `For` loop creates the 2nd shape if the active slide is not in the skipping list.

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub PasteToAll()
    Dim oshpR  As ShapeRange
    Dim T1     As Single
    Dim L1     As Single
    Dim sPage As String
    Dim sIndex As String
    Dim i As Integer, MyRange
    Const SEP_CHAR = ","  ' Modidy as needed 
    ActiveWindow.View.Paste
    Set oshpR = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    T1 = oshpR(1).Top
    L1 = oshpR(1).Left
    sPage = VBA.InputBox("Please input page number(seperated by comma)")
    sPage = SEP_CHAR & sPage & SEP_CHAR
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        sIndex = SEP_CHAR & i & SEP_CHAR
        If VBA.InStr(1, sPage, sIndex) = 0 Then
            Set MyRange = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.Paste
            MyRange(1).Left = L1
            MyRange(1).Top = T1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello!  Thanks so much for the help. I noticed that the shape is pasted immediately on the slide I am currently on when the code is first run, and then will be pasted again to that slide after the slide numbers are entered and submitted into the popout (I am assuming this is what your note was referring to).  Is there a way to fix this?  Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to determin the position (top, left) of shape w/o pasting on current slide?